# Data corrupts when uploading to S3 (PUT) using Axios in React

Tags: reactjs, image, http, amazon-s3, axios

With the following function, I am able to upload images to S3, but I am unable to open the image when I attempt to retrieve it. The following is a function used in a React application that handles the file using 'react-dropzone':

```js
import axios, { post } from 'axios'

import { Buffer } from 'buffer'

const processImage = ({ file }) => {
  const reader = new FileReader()

  reader.onload = async () => {
    const base64data = reader.result
    const bufferdata = Buffer.from(base64data, 'base64')


    const generateSignedS3Url = '/.netlify/functions/get-s3-urls'

    // Obtains signed URLs from a Netlify Serverless Function
    const { data } = await post(generateSignedS3Url, {
      clientFilename: file.name,
      mimeType: file.type,
    }).catch(e => {
      console.error('Error in generating signed url ', e)
    })

    axios({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: data.putUrl,
      data: bufferdata,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': file.type, 'Content-Encoding': 'base64' },
    }).catch(e => {
      console.error(e) 
    })
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```

The following contains the parameters used to obtain the signed URL for the serverless function invoked above:

```js
const putParams = {
      Bucket,
      Key,
      Expires: 2 * 60,
      ContentType: body.mimeType,
      ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    }
    const putUrl = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', putParams)
```

Here, `body.mimeType` would be `'image/jpeg'`.

Scanning from similar Stack Overflow questions, I've ensured the following:

1. The header `'Content-Encoding'` is set to `'base64'`
2. I am using a buffer to send the content using the NPM buffer library (this is a client application)
3. The header `'Content-Type'` matches the file that is being sent up (ie for a file "background.jpg", the header is set to 'image/jpeg')
4. I've also attempted to send without a buffer

I've looked through similar SO questions before submitting. They include [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624346/image-upload-to-s3-does-not-render), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904174/s3-uploading-and-serving-image-with-pre-signed-url), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148168/using-signed-requests-with-aws-s3-and-uploading-photos). There are other ones, but they are for the Node backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reader.result` has a prefix before the encoded data. As described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL):

> The blob's result cannot be directly decoded as Base64 without first removing the Data-URL declaration preceding the Base64-encoded data. To retrieve only the Base64 encoded string, first remove `data:*/*;base64,` from the result.

So you can do something like:

```js
const base64data = reader.result.split(',')[1];
```